# how to set a table to appear upon 1 click via Javascript

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, toggle, visible

I have set my table to hidden via css, but when I run the onclick function via javascript, It takes two clicks (double click) in order to make the table visible again.

Any idea how I can set this to appear with just one click?

Below are the images to my code

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIpNX.jpg)

[CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5l49F.png)

[Javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9cz5.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***if you want to use JQuery in your projects you can do this 
first include jquery in header***

```
<header>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</header>
```

***then just   put in onmousedown   `$('#OperatingScheduler').toggle()`***

```css
table td{border:dashed;border-color:gray;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <button onmousedown="$('#OperatingScheduler').toggle()">Trading Times</button>
  <button>StudioSchedule</button>
</div>

<table id="OperatingScheduler">
  <tr>
    <td>Day</td>
    <td>Time</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TuesDay</td>
    <td>6am-8am</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

***when your projects get complicated and bigger you will need jquery to save you huge effort***

Comment: Thanks for the Tip Rkv, I'm still getting the hang of javascript, so I thought  I should first get a better understanding of it before getting into jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showTable()
{
var x = document.getElementById("OperatingScheduler");
if(x.style.visibility=='visible')
{
  x.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
else
{
  x.style.visibility='visible';
}
}
```

```css
#OperatingScheduler{
visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <button onmousedown="showTable()">Trading Times</button>
  <button>StudioSchedule</button>
</div>

<table id="OperatingScheduler">
  <tr>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Time</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Problem solved.  ;)

Just change the  values in the  if else. What your code does is that, on mouse down it  straight away goes to else. So table once again its  getting hidden. On second click it shows the  table.

Comment: Thanks, Mr Inferior! switching the visibility around in javascript seemed to have done the trick!